# How to achieve D3D output with premultiplied alpha for use with D3DImage in WPF?

Tags: wpf, direct3d, alphablending

We are using a `D3DImage` in WPF to display partly transparent 3D content rendered using Direct3D on a background which is created in WPF. So, we have something like this:

```
<UserControl Background="Blue">
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <D3DImage .../>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</UserControl>
```

Now, we have the problem that anti-aliased edges are not displayed properly. We get some sort of white "glow" effect at some edges, similar to the effect around the text shown in the first picture:

[image]

(taken from http://dvd-hq.info/alpha_matting.php)

The reason is that the data we get from DirectX obviously is *not premultiplied* with the alpha channel. But WPF and the `D3DImage` expect this as their input (see ["Introduction to D3DImage"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage) on CodeProject, section "A Brief Look at D3D Interop Requirements").

I verified that this is actually the problem by multiplying every pixel by its alpha value in C# and using a custom pixel shader. The results were both fine. However, I would like to get this result from DirectX directly.

How can I get premultiplied data from DirectX directly? Can I somehow specify it in the call to `CreateRenderTarget`? I am no DirectX expert, so please excuse if the solution might be obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your DirectX content properly pre-multiplied, you will need a custom ID3D11BlendState.  The [D3D11_BLEND_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct should be set up as follows:

```
AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;
RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = TRUE;

// dest.rgb = src.rgb * src.a + dest.rgb * (1 - src.a)
RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

// dest.a = 1 - (1 - src.a) * (1 - dest.a) [the math works out]
RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_DEST_ALPHA;
RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
```

Create the blend state with [ID3D11Device::CreateBlendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then set it with [ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetBlendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then, just set up the rest of your Direct3D pipeline as normal, and the output to the render-target should have pre-multiplied alpha with correct alpha channel output, for use with Direct2D, WPF, or any other API requiring pre-multiplied content.

Note that if you are using Direct3D 9, the concepts are the same but the API is different. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a good place to get started if you're using 9.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, we are using D3D9 (forgot to mention that), so I could not use this code and I finally handed it over to some colleague with more experience in D3D. Anyway, I assume your answer is correct for D3D11, so I will accept it.

Comment: D3DImage uses D3D9 so this answer is not helpful.